# reading from S3 pre-signed URL using S3Client::GetObject

Tags: c++, amazon-s3

I have existing code using AWS c++ SDK where I instantiate a Aws::S3::S3Client, then set up a Aws::S3::Model::GetObjectRequest with the bucket name, key name and finally call GetObject so I can download from the specified S3 source.

Now I'm trying to also support reading from an S3 source using a pre-signed URL.  The URL contains things like X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential, X-Amz-Signature, etc.

How do I set these up with S3Client/GetObjectRequest so I can download from such a file?  Or will I need to use a different approach to download the file?

Comment: If your input is a pre-signed URL, then just make a standard HTTP GET request to download the file.

Comment: Can I make this call still using S3Client, or do I just use Curl or similar?

Comment: No need to use S3Client, just use some HTTP client.